# Calling 2 methods asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm not sure if my program does exactly what i want or if it could be coded better.
Target would be to call the 2 Methods (CreateHeaderAsync, CombineFilesAsync) and let them work parallel.

I don't think this is the right or a good way to write those ...Async() methods because that looks pretty unclean.

And couldn't i combine the first 4 lines in my CreateFile method to reduce unimportant code and make it more readable?

```
public void CreateFile(string path)
{
    Task<byte[]> headerTask = CreateHeaderAsync();
    Task<byte[]> filesTask = CombineFilesAsync();
    byte[] header = headerTask.Result;
    byte[] files = filesTask.Result;

    byte[] combined = new byte[header.Length + files.Length];

    Buffer.BlockCopy(header, 0, combined, 0, header.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(files, 0, combined, header.Length, files.Length);

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => File.WriteAllBytes(path, combined));
}

private Task<byte[]> CreateHeaderAsync()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int position = 0;
        foreach (ByteFile file in _files)
        {
            sb.Append(file + "?" + position + Environment.NewLine);
            position += file.Length;
        }
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb + "--header_end--" + Environment.NewLine);
    });
}

private Task<byte[]> CombineFilesAsync()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        ByteFile[] arrays = _files.ToArray();

        byte[] rv = new byte[arrays.Sum(a => a.Length)];
        int offset = 0;
        foreach (ByteFile t in arrays)
        {
            var array = Encryption.EncryptBytes(t.Content, "password");

            Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, rv, offset, array.Length);
            offset += array.Length;
        }
        return rv;
    });
}
```

Comment: you seems not waiting them to complete before write. you have to add sync barrier there,

Comment: I am wondering why you don't like the solution as you've posted it. Personally I would try to get rid of the `.Result` reading as I've experienced enough deadlocks when blocking on tasks to try to avoid them but even that would simply replace that with an `await` instead, you would still have the 4 lines. But is that so bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Target would be to call the 2 Methods (CreateHeaderAsync, CombineFilesAsync) and let them work parallel.

Then try Task.WhenAll to asynchronously await their completion.

```
  public async Task CreateFile(string path)
    {
        Task<byte[]> headerTask = CreateHeaderAsync();
        Task<byte[]> filesTask = CombineFilesAsync();

        var allResults = await Task.WhenAll(headerTask, filesTask);
        byte[] header = allResults[0];
        byte[] files = allResults[1];
```

**Reply** to the comment

> Couldn't he also just do byte[] header = await headerTask; byte[] files = await filesTask; Does it matter that he waits for one task even though the other may complete before it?

Ok. This is true. The only thing is that two `await` could resume the caller once more. So I would prefer a single final callback.

Comment: Couldn't he also just do `byte[] header = await headerTask; byte[] files = await filesTask;` instead of the last 6 lines of code in your example? Does it matter that he waits for one task even though the other may complete before it?

Comment: No, they aren't. First you spawn both, then you wait for both, that's not going to run in sequence, it isn't `await` that executes the code in the task, that simply waits for it to complete and then unwraps the result.

Comment: Also, note that `Task.WaitAll` is not what you want in your example, it's `Task.WhenAll`, since `Task.WaitAll` returns `void`.

Comment: Also, `Task.WhenAll` does not return a task that contains the results of those two underlying tasks, you still need to access the `headerTask.Result` property. In this case you can still use `Task.WaitAll`, but not with `await`. To use `await`, you would simply do `await Task.WhenAll(headerTask, filesTask);`, and then unwrap the results.

Comment: WhenAll. A typo! Fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you wish them to run in parallel, you could use WhenAll.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874(v=vs.110).aspx

Something like this:

```
public void CreateFile(string path)
{
    Task<byte[]>[] tasks = new [] { CreateHeaderAsync(), CombineFilesAsync() };

    var resultSet = Task.WhenAll(tasks); // create an aggregate task
    try 
    {
        resultSet.Wait(); // await the results
    }
    catch (AggregateException)
    {
        // handle exceptions in the tasks here
    }

    if (resultSet.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) 
    {
         // get your results
         byte[] header = resultSet.Result[0]; 
         byte[] files = resultSet.Result[1];

         byte[] combined = new byte[header.Length + files.Length];
         Buffer.BlockCopy(header, 0, combined, 0, header.Length);
         Buffer.BlockCopy(files, 0, combined, header.Length, files.Length);

         Task.Factory.StartNew(() => File.WriteAllBytes(path, combined));
    } 
}
```

Also, in this case, I would find Task.Run() to be a little more readable than Task.Factory.StartNew().

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/

It allows you to make the CreateHeaderAsync and CombineFilesAsync a bit smaller by concentrating all the Tasks in the CreateFile method.

```
public void CreateFile(string path)
{
    Task<byte[]>[] tasks = new [] { 
          Task.Run((byte[])CreateHeaderAsync), 
          Task.Run((byte[])CombineFilesAsync)};

    // rest of the method 
}

private byte[] CombineFilesAsync()
{
     ByteFile[] arrays = _files.ToArray();

     byte[] rv = new byte[arrays.Sum(a => a.Length)];
     int offset = 0;
     foreach (ByteFile t in arrays)
     {
        var array = Encryption.EncryptBytes(t.Content, "password");

        Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, rv, offset, array.Length);
        offset += array.Length;
     }
     return rv;
}
```

Wrote this a bit fast and without checking, apologies if any weird mistakes snuck in there :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for async/await pattern. Using `Task.Result` causes calling thread to be blocked, which in some cases can lead to deadlock.


If you do not want to play with task creation options and you do not want to be able to cancel tasks I recommend you to create tasks using `Task.Run(() => {})`. In most cases that is just what you need.


So change your async methods signature to `public async ...` and then instead of calling task.Result just await that tasks:

```
var taskResult = await MyMethodAsync();
```